# Datetime in Jython

Tags: python, jython, apache-nifi

I need to find out if today is a business day.

In CPython I would use datetime for that:

```
import datetime
today=datetime.date.today()
if today.isoweekday()==0 or today.isoweekday()==6
   print "weekend"
else:
   print "weekday"
```

However since I'm using NiFi I'm forced to use Jython. Which apparently implements datetime as an alias for some JDBC class.
If I try the code above in NiFi I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'java.sql.Date' object has no attribute 'isoweekday' in  at line number 8.

How can I find out the day of the week in this condition?

Comment: I don't see this problem in jython2.7.0.  Which version are you using?

Comment: Supposed to be 2.7 also. However I don't know how NiFi calls it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to perform this determination in Jython? Apache NiFi exposes a custom Expression Language which allows you to perform some operations in flowfile attributes or content without loading a completely new evaluation environment. By using the [EL date functions](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#dates) with the [Java time formatting syntax (specifically `E` -- *day of week*)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), you could craft a boolean expression that would return `weekday` or `weekend` appropriately.

This example uses `now()` which returns the current time, but you can also have an existing attribute value like `12/10/2018` or a similar string that can be parsed with `toDate()` according to the EL docs.

`${now():format("E"):in("Sat", "Sun"):ifElse("weekend", "weekday")}`

This is tested on Apache NiFi 1.9.0-SNAPSHOT but should work on any version after 1.2.0, when `ifElse` was introduced.

Comment: I don't need to it in Jython. However it was part of a bigger script that also check if the date is in a array of Holidays (we have plenty of those here in Brazil)